# Define numbers in a html text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to all numbers in my html text have different font-size with other character (or different font-family or different font-weight or ...).
How to define numbers character? Is this possible with jquery? Can you help me?!

Comment: In a very long text, is this a optimize solution?

Comment: You have a function `isNumeric()` in jQuery with its doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric but I think that regex would be better.

Comment: @AGuif i think isNumeric will be redundant since you already have to tokenize

Comment: Yes, that's why regex is better. `isNumeric()` would be useful if html elements have only numbers or only other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for a JQuery solution, I transformed @raam86 's answer to jQuery, it looks like this:

```
$("div").html($("div").text().replace(/\d+/g, 
    function(m){ return "<span class='number'>" + m + "</span>" }));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9QKM/4/)**

Answer (score 3):

Using regex you match the numbers an wrap them in a span with a class. No jquery needed.

```
    string.replace(/\d+/g,function(match){
    return "<span class='number'>" + match + "</span>"})
```

You can control the number design with css:

```
 .number{
   color:red;
   }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9QKM/3/)

Comment: In demo, the color of numbers isn't red. or I may be a mistake?

Comment: @mr.soroush updated fiddle to work on firefox. MDN doesn't support innerText

Comment: Looks red to me, too. What browser are you using, @mr.soroush?